# Using swf resourced on Android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, flash

I have 12 .swf files with sound effects, and I need to use them in a new app I'm developing on Android Studio 1.2.

I have researched the issue and found that up to ver 4.0 it was possible by using WebView and embedding the swf in an HTML file. There are no solutions for later versions, does anyone have a solution?

Should I convert the files to a different format? I tried Gif but it's to heavy each file 1.5MB.  I was thinking about HTML5 but it does not support sound.
Thank you in advance.